# Upgrading from Micronaut 3 to Micronaut 4 stops endpoints from being loaded

Tags: java, micronaut

We have a Micronaut application running on Micronaut version 3.x. This application is using a shared library, which contains a few controllers (`@Endpoint` classes) which are part of every application. An example is this:

```
@Endpoint(id = "ping", defaultSensitive = false)
public class PingEndpoint {

    @Read
    public String ping() {
        return "pong";
    }

}
```

Now that we've attempted an upgrade to Micronaut 4, this controller is no longer being loaded. In Micronaut 3 I can see the following output:

```
2023-08-15 16:01:31.805 DEBUG --- [    Test worker] i.m.web.router.DefaultRouteBuilder       : Created Route to @Endpoint monitoring.PingEndpoint: GET /transactions/ping -> PingEndpoint#ping ()
```

In Micronaut 4, I see my Endpoints being created too, but not this one. I couldn't find anything related to this in the breaking changes. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You mentioned that it is a shared library. Did you recompile the shared library using Micronaut 4?

Comment: No, I did not recompile it. The shared lib is still using Micronaut 3. I can try this, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, that is required to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, a recompilation of your shared library using Micronaut 4 is required in order to make Micronaut 4 discover your beans.

See also: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/discussions/9414